# Python: Handling Date/Time with AM/PM information

Tags: python, datetime

In my Excel data, column 1 is titled 'Time'. It contains data and time information as follow: 7/26/2018 2:15:00 AM

In my python code, I am trying to use pd.to_datetime to convert it into date/time format.

Here is my code. It looks correct but it doesn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime


#Basis 
pf=0.9
datatimeinterval_mins = 15

#Pump/fan design specs
des_ampere = 327
des_voltage_kv = 3.3
des_kw = 1600
des_flow_nm3s = 49.9
lowclamp=35

min_flowratio = lowclamp/50

print(min_flowratio)

#Load dataset
    df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Z003V0EE\Desktop\Python Test\Datasetrev0.xlsx', sheet_name=0, parse_date=[0])
    print(df.head())

    #Set index
    df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S %p')
    df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)

    #actual operating parameters
    df['actualkw'] = (df.PAF2Current * des_voltage_kv * 0.9 * np.math.sqrt(3))
    df['actualflowratio'] = (df.PAF2AirFlow / des_flow_nm3s)
    df['expectedkw'] = (df.actualflowratio**3 * des_kw)
    df['kwsavings'] = (df.actualkw - df.expectedkw)

    df =  df.round(2)
    print(df.head())

    plt.plot(df.index, df.PAF2AirFlow)
```

Can anyone spot my mistake please?

I get the following error:
ValueError: time data '7/26/2018 2:15:00 AM' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S %p' (match)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please show us more of the code you are using and expected output/result?

Comment: I am trying to plot some parameters against date/time. But the date/time is not recognised as a date/time format yet.

Comment: I have updated my post with more of my code. I get the following error:

Comment: ValueError: time data '7/26/2018 2:15:00 AM' does not match format '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S %p' (match)

Comment: please put this error in the question, it does no service being in the comments

Comment: yeah, thanks for the reminder. I have added this to my original post.

Answer (score 2):

Change your format to `'%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'` works for me. Note the capital Y.

In [related docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html), `%y` means double-digit year, while `%Y` means four digit representation of year.

In addition, you should use `%I` instead of `%H` as the former is 12-hour and the latter is 24-hour.

Comment: ValueError: time data datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 8, 0, 0) does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p' (match)

Comment: @Ombre why would you convert to datetime when you already have a datetime object

Comment: I am trying to set the 'datetime' column as index. Then plot a few parameters against the index. If I do not convert to datetime, then I end up with the following error on my plot code line. "43108 is not a string"

Comment: @Ombre from your error message, you already got datetime objects, so you can't `to_datetime()` a datetime, maybe try to identify what's in your `datetime` column first?

Comment: Alright thanks a lot @kevin Fang. Let me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [dateutil.parser](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) to convert string to datetime. It's pretty slick and will avoid any issues if your spreadsheet ever changes the time formatting.