# How to read AM/PM times in pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, parsing, timestamp

I am dealing with a csv file containing a column called **startTime**, containing times.

When opening this file with **Excel**, the times appear as AM/PM times in the formula bar, although the timestamps in the column appear improperly formatted:

[image]

```
startTime
16:02.0
17:45.0
18:57.0
20:23.0
```

When reading this file using pandas' `read_csv`, I am unable to format these timestamps properly:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('example_file.csv')
print(df.startTime)
```

Simply yields:

```
0        16:02.0 
1        17:45.0 
2        18:57.0 
3        20:23.0
```

I first attempted to convert the output Series using `pd.to_datetime(df.startTime,format=" %H%M%S")` but this yields the following error message:

> **time data '16:02.0' does not match format ' %H%M%S' (match)**

I then tried `pd.to_datetime(df.startTime,format=" %I:%M:%S %p")` based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404307/python-handling-date-time-with-am-pm-information), in order to account for the AM/PM convention, but this returned the same error message.

**How can I use pandas to format these timestamps like Excel automatically does?**

Comment: Can you upload the content of your csvfile as text instead of image, please?

Comment: Sure, I will update my question and include the contents of the csv file as a text, but I also would like the reader to visualize Excel's formula bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your csv file has text, not datetime, so you need to first convert text stored in this column to pandas datetime object, then you can convert this pandas datetime object to the kind of format that you want via a `strftime` method:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['startTime']).dt.strftime(date_format = '%I:%M:%S %p')
```

Outputs:

```
0   04:02:00 PM
1   05:45:00 PM
2   06:57:00 PM
3   08:23:00 PM
```

**Note:** these values are string values, not datetime.

**Edit for this specific issue:**

A quick format to add 00h to your timestamp before converting to get midnight AM:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['startTime'].apply(lambda x: f'00:{x}')).dt.strftime(date_format = '%I:%M:%S %p')
```

Outputs:

```
0   00:16:02 AM
1   00:17:45 AM
2   00:18:57 AM
3   00:20:23 AM
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I understand that using `strftime` makes sense when dealing with strings. Your snippet returns the following error message `ParserError: hour must be in 0..23: 29:47.0`. I will try changing `date_format` to fix this issue.

Comment: It will not fix the issue, your data looks like it's in 'Minutes:Seconds.Milliseconds' in which case your timestamp representation in Excel has to have extra formatting/data transformation.

Comment: @Sheldon do your minute values exceed 59 for any value? I.e. do you have any values where the first part of your timestamp is >=60 (e.g. 65:02.0)?

Comment: Nope, `df['startTime'].max()` returns '59:59.0'

Comment: Please notice I've made some changes (adding 00 instead of 12, because 12 turns into PM, but you need to have AM) @Sheldon

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['startTime'].str.strip(), format='%H:%M.%S')

0   1900-01-01 16:02:00
1   1900-01-01 17:45:00
2   1900-01-01 18:57:00
3   1900-01-01 20:23:00
Name: startTime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your solution returns the same error message: `ValueError: time data '29:47.0' does not match format '%H:%M.%S' (match)`

Comment: I'm waiting your data to fix my answer.

Comment: That sounds like you're doing something extra in your excel that changes your values @Sheldon, what does your timestamp (specifically 16:02.0) represent?

Comment: I think you have extra spaces. Strip before apply `to_datetime`. I fixed my answer.

Comment: @dm2 16:02.0 represents 12:16:02 AM.

Comment: OK. You have to parse manually your startTime.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will write a function to manually parse startTime then.

Answer (score 0):

Coerce to datetetime and extract time using dt.strftime

```
df['startTime']=pd.to_datetime(df['startTime']).dt.strftime('%I:%M.%S%p')
```